# Python function LocateOnScreen to detect numbers on screen, starting from 0 to 9

Tags: python, pyautogui

[numbers on screen][1][numbers on screen][2]I want to use python function "LocateOnScreen" to detect numbers on screen. I wonder if I could use it in logical operators or conditional operators. I want it to detect if a particular number appears in the specified region on the screen, starting from 0 to 9 for the 1st digit. If it does, it returns true, narrows down the specified region, and detects the 2nd digit. If it cannot find, it returns false.

```
import pyautogui
import pyscreeze
import cv2
pyautogui.click(400, 750,duration=0.4)
pyautogui.sleep(2)
pyautogui.useImageNotFoundException()

Xregion=(660,669,200,30)
try:

    Xcoordinate=pyautogui.locateOnScreen("x.png", confidence=0.98, 
region=Xregion)

    print(Xcoordinate)
    print(Xcoordinate[0]+Xcoordinate[2])
    Lregion=(Xcoordinate[0]+Xcoordinate[2], Xregion[2], Xcoordinate[2]*3, Xregion[3])

    Lcoordinate=pyautogui.locateOnScreen("Lbracket.png", confidence=0.98, region=Lregion)
    print(Xregion)
    print("Lre=",Lregion)
    print("Lcoor=",Lcoordinate)
    region0=(Lcoordinate[0]+Lcoordinate[2], Xregion[2], Xcoordinate[2], Xregion[3])
    try:
        coordinate0=pyautogui.locateOnScreen("0.png", confidence=0.98, region=region0)
        print(region0)
        print(coordinate0)
        Rregion=(coordinate0[0]+coordinate0[2], Xregion[2], coordinate0[2], Xregion[3])
        Rcoordinate=pyautogui.locateOnScreen("Rbracket.png", confidence=0.98, region=Rregion)
        print(Rcoordinate)
        print("0")
    except:
        try:
            coordinate1=pyautogui.locateOnScreen("1.png", confidence=0.98, region=region0)
            print(coordinate1)
        except:
            print("no1")
            print(region0)
except:
    print("NoX")
```

My problem involves 2 questions, for the 1st digit, how to handle it if 0 is not found? Second, how to narrow down the region by adding coordinate numbers of the 1st-found digi to the existing region.

Thank you for your help.

The program so far returns the following:

```
    Box(left=692, top=671, width=12, height=15)
    704
    (660, 669, 200, 30)
    Lre= (704, 669, 36, 30)
    Lcoor= Box(left=720, top=671, width=10, height=19)
    no1
    (730, 669, 12, 30)
    PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOTdN.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVClZ.png
```

Comment: Use `try/except` to catch if it's not found.